# accessing bytes of an integer in c

Tags: c

i have values like 12, 13 which i want assign to single integer example, k.
i tried the following program but i am not getting expected results.

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int k = 0;
printf("k address is %u\n", &k);
char* a = &k;
printf("%u\n", a);
*(a) = 12;
a++;
printf("%u\n", a);
*(a) = 13;
printf("k is %d\n",k);
return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
 k address is 3213474664
 3213474664
 3213474665
 k is 3340
```

Comment: 13*256 + 12 = 3340. What were you expecting?

Comment: think if i have ip address 128.99.1.20 which is a char pointer now i have to stripped of '.' and got it as 12899120 in a separate int variables like a, b, c, d, now i want all these in single integer.

Comment: Then please edit your question so that it includes an actual question (i.e. what you want to achieve).

Comment: FFS please tell us what your expected results are.  As others have said, on a little endian machine, 3340 is the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify bytes in an integer in an endian-independent way, you should use shifts and bitwise operators.

For example, if you were trying to store an IP address of 1.2.3.4 into a 32-bit integer, you could do:

```
unsigned int addr = (1 << 24) | (2 << 16) | (3 << 8) | 4;
```

This guarantees that `1` is the most significant byte and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

On your system, `int`s are evidently stored in [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian) format, because 13*256 + 12 = 3340.